# Rsepc testing iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, iteration

I'm writing the test for a method like this:

```
  def get_team_members(project_id)
    team_members = []

    Result.where(project_id: project_id).each do |result|
      user = User.find_by(id: result.user_id)
      team_members.push(user) unless user.nil?
    end

    team_members
  end
```

When I'm testing the case when only 1 `result` record is found, I could do

```
allow(Result).to receive(:where).with(project_id:project_id).and_return([result1])

allow(User).to receive(:find_by).with(id: valid_result[:user_id]).and_return(nil)
```

or

```
allow(Result).to receive(:where).with(project_id:project_id).and_return([result1])

allow(User).to receive(:find_by).with(id: valid_result[:user_id]).and_return(user1)
```

**Question1:** If I want to test the case when 2 `result` records are found

```
allow(Result).to receive(:where).with(project_id:project_id).and_return([result1, result2])
```

And for `result1` a matching `user` is found (`user1`), for `result2` no matching `user` is found (`nil`).

In this case the expected returning value should be `team_members = [user1]`.

How can I mock `User.find_by()` twice with different returning values (`user1, nil`)?

**Question2:** Do I really need to test the case I mentioned above?

Comment: This is not relevant to the testing question you asked, but your query is highly inefficient – you’re structuring it as an N+1 query – that is, for a Result with N team members you’ll hit the database once (for your `where` statement) and then once per team member. This feels like something where you should be able to take advantage of Rails’ built-in `has_many :through` option: if a `Project` has_many :results, and each  `Result` belongs to a `:user`, then declaring that a project `has_many :users, through: :results` would mean that `project.users` would give you the collection you want.

Comment: Yes Scott you are right. The database design is not so good. It was built by previous team members and I'm just developing upon it. I would probably have to update the schema later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question 2, yes it's better to test the scenario where there are more than one record since you have a loop.
How about you mock your data like this:

```
let(:user_id1) { 1 }
let(:user_id2) { 2 }
let(:user1) { double(:user, id: user_id1) }
let(:user2) { double(:user, id: user_id2) }

before do
  allow(Result).to receive(:where).with(project_id: project_id).and_return([result1, result2])
  allow(result1).to receive(:user_id).and_return(user_id1)
  allow(result1).to receive(:user_id).and_return(user_id2)
  allow(User).to receive(:find_by).with(id: user_id1).and_return(user1)
  allow(User).to receive(:find_by).with(id: user_id2).and_return(user2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Sachin! Your answer works in my code.